# .net SimpleMembership, timeout possible?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using SimpleMembership with mvc4. Is it possible to set a timeout period for this? Similar to setting the to out period for normal forms authentication within the confit file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not exactly clear what type of timeout you are trying to set. But if it's a timeout to the database you can set it in the connectionstring like this:

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30";
```

Comment: Apoligies, tbh I don't don't SimpleMembership very well. It's not a database timeout I want. It's a login inactive expirey time I want to set. Does SimpleMembership still use the forms authentication confit section? If so I would set it there? Thanks

Comment: Oh yea authentication timeout is still set in the forms section of the web.config.